Is it possible for SIGALRM to be delivered after setitimer() disables the timer?
I have some code like this that has failed once on CI and once locally, though I cannot reproduce it reliably.  The code is like this:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    // Ignore SIGALRM
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);

    // Set a timer for every 100us
    struct itimerval ival = {0};
    ival.it_value.tv_usec = 100;
    ival.it_interval.tv_usec = 100;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &ival, NULL);

    // Busy-wait 1s
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) <= start);

    // Disable the timer
    ival.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &ival, NULL);

    // Restore the default SIGALRM disposition
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);

    // Busy-wait 1s
    start = time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) <= start);

    return 0;
}

The failure I observe is the process terminating due to SIGALRM (the shell says "Alarm clock").  Is it possible that a SIGALRM from the timer is delivered after the final setitimer() returns?
The POSIX wording for setitimer() is not very clear about the ordering between signals and setitimer() disabling the timer.
I have observed this crash once on Linux and once on macOS.

Your example doesn't include, but I just want to double check.  Is your "real" code using sleep() anywhere while this is going on?

@AndyDalton Good question, but no, the real test doesn't use sleep() (or alarm()).  It increments an atomic count from a signal handler, and spins until the count reaches a limit.

This turned out to not be an issue with setitimer() at all, but rather an ABA problem with my signal handler registration code.  I basically had an array of signal handlers so that I could dynamically add/remove them during the test.  But if you have a loop doing
while (true) {
    // At least one signal handler is always present
    // handlers[] is an array of atomic pointers
    handlers[1] = handler; // A1
    handlers[0] = NULL;    // A2
    handlers[0] = handler; // A3
    handlers[1] = NULL;    // A4
}

while the signal handler does
bool handled = false;
if (handlers[0]) { // B1
    handlers[0]();
    handled = true;
}
if (handlers[1]) { // B2
    handlers[1]();
    handled = true;
}
if (!handled) {
    signal(signo, SIG_DFL);
    raise(signo);
}

Then the interleaving A1, A2, B1, A3, A4, B2 will cause it to think both handlers are NULL and re-raise the fatal signal.

#include <stddef.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // Ignore SIGALRM
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);

    // Set a timer for every 100us
    struct itimerval ival = {0};
    ival.it_value.tv_usec = 100;
    ival.it_interval.tv_usec = 100;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &ival, NULL);

    // Busy-wait 1s
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) <= start);

    // Block SIGALRM
    sigset_t mask, oldmask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);

    // Disable the timer
    ival.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &ival, NULL);

    // Unblock SIGALRM
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL);

    // Restore the default SIGALRM disposition
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);

    // Busy-wait 1s
    start = time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) <= start);

    return 0;
}


Please don't just dump uncommented code in an answer. What's different? What was your reason for changing it? Why is this better?

The difference seems to be the addition of sigprocmask() to block/unblock SIGALRM, but I don't see how that helps
